# WSO2 scim api /Groups/roleId takes too much time to update

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.10 version. As per requirement we can add and remove new roles form our application and call the following API to update groups with users. I am doing thi sas bulk operation as some time it requires to update as bulk. Even for 1 role update it takes 6 seconds where no of users are 30-40 k and in production where users are 90-95 k takes more than 12 seconds.
Is there any way to update in less time. Am I not following the correct way. Please suggest.

```
foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                var groupBulkOperation = new WSO2GroupBulkSCIMResourceOperationSchema();

                groupBulkOperation.BulkId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                groupBulkOperation.Method = "PATCH";
                groupBulkOperation.Path = "/Groups/" + role.value;
                groupBulkOperation.Data = new WSO2GroupBulkSCIMResourceDataSchema
                {
                    Operations = new List<WSO2GroupOperationSchema>
                    {
                        new WSO2GroupOperationSchema
                        {
                            op = "add",
                            path = "members",
                            value = new List<Members>
                            {
                                new Members
                                {
                                    display = userName,
                                    value = userId
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                requestModel.Operations.Add(groupBulkOperation);
            }

                var response = await CommonServiceResponceModel(
                KeyObj.WSO2BaseURL + "scim2/Bulk",
                Method.POST,
                SerializeObject(requestModel)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this operation for the `Primary` user-store or the `Secondary` userstore?

Comment: I am doing for the Primary User-store. I have multi-role system in my application and roles can be added or removed from application. So whenever role is getting added. we call scim API to update role which takes lot of time to update. Ideally any patch update should not take millisecond to update.

Comment: As per your argument `Even for 1 role update, it takes 6 seconds where no of users are 30-40 k` do you experience this time when the patch request add new 30-40k users to the particular group OR when the adding one or two users to a group which has members around 30-40k users at the moment?